# Python datetime variable stored in array/list

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

Is it possible to store datetime variable into array/list without converting them into a string?? The following code as shown below:

```
for (x,y) in detec:
        if y<(pos_linha+offset) and y>(pos_linha-offset):
            count += 1
            cv2.line(frame1, (25, pos_linha), (1200, pos_linha), (0,127,255), 3)
            detec.remove((x,y))
            print("car is detected : "+str(count))
            #text = "Detected"
            time.sleep(1)


            timing = datetime.now()
            
            
            timing_array.append(timing)
            print (timing_array[0])
            print (timing_array[a])

            # x = [datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for s in date_str]
            
            *for b in timing_array:
              
                if count == 1:
                    break
                elif count == 2:
                    time_difference = b[1] -b[0]
                    print(time_difference)*
                    
                    #timing_array.pop(1)
                # print (b[a])
                # print (b[0])
            a += 1
```

Comment: There is also a for loop before this which allows contours to be made

Comment: Yes.  Try a clean-sheet example.  Your code above is not reproducible because of the asterisks, `a`, and `count` variables etc.

Comment: What does a clean-sheet example mean? I have just included the entire code into the block

Answer (score 0):

"clean sheet example" means try to make a simple minimum reproducible code block that shows the problem/issue.  You will get better answers on this site if folks can copy out your code and tinker with it.  Your pre-edit code (and this one) are not easily reproduced by someone who might help you because there's a bunch of stuff missing and it goes beyond the scope of your question.

The answer to your question is yes.  Example:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime                                           

In [2]: my_times = []                                                           

In [3]: a = datetime.now()                                                      

In [4]: my_times.append(a)                                                      

In [5]: recovered_a = my_times.pop()                                            

In [6]: print(recovered_a)                                                      
2020-10-01 07:00:24.238325
```